# Creating Custom Authentication in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.3

i have project which is developed in core php .Now i have created few api in that
I am able to get all data in laravel but now i have bit problem with login authentication .

```
  public function postLogin(Request $request) {

       //    print_r($request->all());

           $data['email']=$request->email;
            $data['password']=$request->password;
        $response=  ApiModel::userLogin($data);

      //  Auth::login($response[0]);
     //   Auth::loginUsingId($response[0]->id);
       echo "<pre>";
     print_r($response[0]);

    }
```

I am trying to create authentication session but its giving error. i have tried following methods but it seems to be not working

```
 Auth::login($response[0]);
Auth::loginUsingId($response[0]->id);
```

Can any one help me how to keep user session using api

Error

> ErrorException in SessionGuard.php line 408: Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an instance of
>   Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of stdClass given,
>   called in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\collab\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager.php
>   on line 294 and defined

Comment: What mean keep session in api? if you use rests there can not be sessions, because it's havent states.

Comment: i mean i am passing data to api from laravel.then from api response i am getting all data of user.that need to keep in auth user session

Comment: Can you share the the user model used? Also the `piModel::userLogin()` method.

Comment: @Sandeesh.i dont have user model since i am using api and its in core php

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Auth::attempt(['fieldname'=>'value','someother'=>'anothervalue']);`

Comment: Thanks .but i  am passing data to api from laravel.then from api response i am getting all data of user.that need to keep in auth user session

Comment: so no database for your laravel ?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the 
quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the correct auth guard information in `config/auth.php`. The `Auth::login()` method expects you to pass a `User` model instance by default and this model should implement `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable`.

You should set the default guard provider to use `database` driver instead of eloquent and set the correct table name. You can then use `Auth::loginUsingId()` to login a user using their id.

But if you do not want to connect your database to Laravel then just rely on the API response and perform your action based on that. You cannot force an authenticated session this way.